# Changing Window Title in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder, title

I'm new to Objective C and Cocoa - and I'm having a really hard time changing the title on one of my windows. Usually I would press the outside of the window, and then in Window Attributes Inspector there's the title area - however for this particular project it has a name in that box and when I run the application, the title bar still says untitled. Am I missing something? I haven't binded the title to a data source or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it programmatically it's really easy: `[window setTitle:@"Window Title"];`

Answer (score 2):

For a document window, it will use the document's `displayName` as the window's title.

Comment: any help on where I would find that? It's not in the attribute inspector, or anywhere I can find on Interface Builder. I also don't see anything about that in my code

Comment: @Zakman411: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Tasks/SubclassNSDocument.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000028-BCIJGBIF

Comment: Thanks Bavarious! I see it says to customize a document's window title properly, subclass NSWindowController and override windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName. Would I just create a new class that has NSWindowController as it's superclass? Being new to this, it's still challenging to understand the documentation

Comment: I have this line of code from documentation:

- (NSString *)windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName:(NSString *)displayName

But I don't understand where to put that...

Answer (score -1):

[That's because you checked this button when you create this project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XROf.jpg)

[You can remove it in your info.plist.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Desp6.png)

Type in your own title in Storyboard. 
And check the window to "is Inital Controller"

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45296657) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it's not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question and flag for undeletion. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)