# Cocoa Mac Application Title says: "untitled"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I have created a document based Mac OSX application, and when I'm editing in Interface Builder, the title is correct (I filled out that portion of the inspector) but once the program runs, the application title is 'Untitled'. How can I change it? In my IB Doc Window, I have instances of Files Owner, First Responder,  NSApplication, and NSWindow. There is no view controller, is that the issue? I'm new to Cocoa..

Comment: It will probably change to the name of your document once you save it (or open one).

Comment: It does. But is there a way to set it to a default? I'd prefer that it doesn't say 'Untitled'

Comment: Zakman411: Naming a new, unsaved document “untitled” is the correct way according to the HIG. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGWindows/XHIGWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-CHDHBCGE Why do you want to violate that convention?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One solution is to override `-displayName` in your `NSDocument` subclass:

```
- (NSString *)displayName {
    if (![self fileURL])
        return @"Some custom untitled string";

    return [super displayName];
}
```

You can also check out `NSWindowController`'s `-windowTitleForDocumentDisplayName:` if you're using custom window controllers.

Answer (score 1):

you have created a document based Cocoa application. For new documents, Cocoa sets the proposed name of the document to 'Untitled'.

Comment: Right, but do you know how to change that?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you checked **Create Document-Based Application** when you created this project:

[image: new project options]

You can remove it from `info.plist` by clicking the **-** button next to **Document types**:

[image: info.plist]

Type in your own title in Storyboard and check the window to "is Inital Controller". After you run your project again, it will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the application menu title? That is changed to match the name of the application at runtime. The simplest way to change it would be to change the Product Name build setting on your target in Xcode.

Comment: That setting actually has the correct name but it still won't show. What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

```
- (NSString *)displayName
{   
    NSMutableString *displayName = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[super displayName]];

    if ([self fileURL] == nil) {
        NSString *firstCharacter = [[displayName substringToIndex:1] lowercaseString];
        [displayName deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
        [displayName insertString:firstCharacter atIndex:0];
    }

    return [NSString stringWithString:displayName];
}
```

Comment: Could you add some description to that code?  What does it do?  How does it do it?  Thanks